# How to get notified when the message body is changed in an outlook addin?

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

I have an outlook add in that I want to be able to have a word counter or a notification to the user when the message body of the mailitem reaches a certain amount of words.

Is there any event similar to the Change-event that exists on the `OlkTexxtBox` for the `_DDocSiteControl` that could be used for this purpose?